# Scope Order by Count with Conditions Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, count, scope, conditional-statements

I have a model `Category` that `has_many` `Pendencies`. I would like to create a scope that order the categories by the amount of Pendencies that has `active = true` without excluding `active = false`.

What I have so far is:

```
scope :order_by_pendencies, -> { left_joins(:pendencies).group(:id).order('COUNT(pendencies.id) DESC')}
```

This will order it by number of pendencies, but I want to order by pendencies that has `active = true`.

Another try was:

```
scope :order_by_pendencies, -> { left_joins(:pendencies).group(:id).where('pendencies.active = ?', true).order('COUNT(pendencies.id) DESC')}
```

This will order by number of pendencies that has `pendencies.active = true`, but will exclude the `pendencies.active = false`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey man. The order tag says don't use. I don't understand your question very well but the tag's gotta go.

Comment: Hello, Joshua. Thank you for the answer. I didn't really understand what you mean by order tag. My question is this:

 imagine that I have the following: category 1 with 10 pendencies (2 active = true and 8 active =false); category 2 with 8 pendencies (6 active = true and 2 active = false); category 3 with 15 pendencies (15 active = false)

I want the order to be: Category 2, Category 1, Category 3

Comment: I could solve this problem in C#. Sorry, I don't know Ruby.

Comment: Thank you for trying, Jushua. Could you please post your answer in C#? Maybe I can have an insight if I see It

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to sort by the amount of active pendencies without ignoring categories that have no active pendencies.

That would be something like:

```
scope :order_by_pendencies, -> { 
  active_count_q = Pendency.
    group(:category_id).
    where(active: true).
    select(:category_id, "COUNT(*) AS count")

  joins("LEFT JOIN (#{active_count_q.to_sql}) AS ac ON ac.category_id = id").
    order("ac.count DESC")
}
```

The equivalent SQL query:

```
SELECT *, ac.count 
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT category_id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM pendencies
    GROUP BY category_id
    WHERE active = true
  ) AS ac ON ac.category_id = id
ORDER BY ac.count DESC
```

Note that if there are no active pendencies for a category, the count will be null and will be added to the end of the list.
A similar subquery could be added to sort additionally by the total amount of pendencies...

Answer (score 1):

C# answer as requested:

```
method() {
    ....OrderBy((category) => category.Count(pendencies.Where((pendency) => pendency.Active))
}
```

Or in straight SQL:

```
SELECT category.id, ..., ActivePendnecies
  FROM (SELECT category.id, ..., count(pendency) ActivePendnecies
          FROM category
          LEFT JOIN pendency ON category.id = pendency.id AND pendnecy.Active = 1
          GROUP BY category.id, ...) P
 ORDER BY ActivePendnecies;
```

We have to output `ActivePendnecies` in SQL even if the code will throw it out because otherwise the optimizer is within its rights to throw out the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

For now I developed the following (it's working, but I believe that it's not the best way):

```
  scope :order_by_pendencies, -> { scoped = Category.left_joins(:pendencies)
                                            .group(:id)
                                            .order('COUNT(pendencies.id) DESC')
                                            .where('pendencies.active = ?', true)
                                   all = Category.all
                                   (scoped + all).uniq}
```